# How to install Windows store app programmatically in UWP?

Tags: download, windows-store-apps, uwp, appx

I want to install an windows store application programmatically from UWP application. I am able to redirect to the Windows store application page but what i want is the application should install automatically from store. Is there any to achieve this in UWP?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is, but such app need Package Policy Control capability (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations). Also you must have direct access to appx package of app to install. Then you can use [PackageManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br240960) class. But this app can't be pushed to Windows store without special permission from MSFT or you must use sideloading (installing without Windows store). So it's almost unusable...